# In PhpSpreadSheet I want the calculated or final value of cells instead of the formula when reading an xlsx file. How can I do this?

Tags: formula, calculation, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PhpSpreadSheet to read the content of an xlsx file into an array. Unfortunately, the cells are giving the formula instead of the final value. Is there a way to just get the final value instead of the formula ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calculation engine more information in the documentation [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/calculation-engine/).